# Restore Deleted database from MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

Someone enter in my mongo database and deleted my database, creating another called "Warning" with one document saying: "Your Database is downloaded and backed up on our secured servers. To recover your lost data: Send 0.6 BTC to our BitCoin ".

Is there anyway to recover the deleted database ?

I think this is a logical deleted,thus i hope that exist some log to recover this database.

Comment: Do you have any backups in place? Otherwise you probably cannot restore the data

Comment: unhappy i didn't make any backup in this database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly, you have been the victim of the increasingly popular MongoDb ransomware attacks:

- https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/security/massive-wave-of-mongodb-ransom-attacks-makes-26-000-new-victims/
- https://www.zdnet.com/article/mongodb-ransacking-starts-again-hackers-ransom-26000-unsecured-instances/
- https://www.trustwave.com/Resources/SpiderLabs-Blog/Protecting-Yourself-from-MongoDB-Ransomware/

Without a backup, you won't be able to get your data back.

Don't send 0.6btc to any address. It is **incredibly unlikely** the attacker took a backup either.

Andreas Nilsson, who is MongoDB's director of product security wrote a blog post on [preventing such attacks](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/how-to-avoid-a-malicious-attack-that-ransoms-your-data).

Comment: how it is possible my mongodb hacked with a user and password ? There is anyway to protect it ?

Comment: weak password, no brute-force protection, default port exposed to the internet, there's many ways.

Comment: i've edited the answer to include a link to a blog post by mongodb on how to prevent this

Comment: @RonaldoLanhellas you're welcome. Please mark as answer if it helped

Comment: Hi, how can I check if Mongo has backup in order to try recover it?I had similar problem , my collections are missing from the db and I had this message in a README file "All your data is a backed up. You must pay 0.015 BTC to 1jAzyxPREckuUPwifEbiUKgDfE5racmph 48 hours for recover it. After 48 hours expiration we will leaked and exposed all your data"

Comment: @user2829319 if you don't know if you've got a backup, you don't have a backup.

Comment: and without backup there is no way I can find them right?

Comment: @user2829319 afraid not