# How to setup authentication on mongoDB on docker-compose with nodejs?

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, authentication, mongoose

I want to setup basic authentication while connecting to the mongoDB database using my nodejs application.

Looked at the documentation for mongo image by specifying

```
environment:
    - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=admin
    - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=pass
```

But this does not seem to work, when I use the connection string in nodejs (mongoose) as

```
mongodb://admin:pass@mongo:27017/myDatabase
```

I would just like to setup basic authentication to prevent any ransomware attacks like this :

[Stackoverflow MongoDB Ransomware](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52259187/13922219)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME` and `MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD` are used to setup superuser account to manage overall databases.
You can connect as admin permission using this connection string
`mongodb://<MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME>:<MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD>@mongo:27017` and create a database `myDatabase`, after that you also have to create user with
a role to allow query database.

For example

```
> use myDatabase
> db.createUser({user: "user", pwd: "user", roles:["dbOwner"]})
```

Then you can connect with this string

```
mongodb://user:user@mongo:27017/myDatabase
```